# WPF: The toolbar is a keyboard trap

Tags: wpf, keyboard, toolbar

I have the following XAML code:

```
<ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ComboBox  x:Name="ComboboxFontname" ToolTip="Auswahlliste um Schriftart festzulegen" ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}" SelectedIndex="0" Width="200" GotFocus="ComboBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus"/>
                <ComboBox  x:Name="ComboboxFontsize" ToolTip="Auswahlliste um Schriftgröße festzulegen" SelectedIndex="0" Width="45" GotFocus="ComboBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="12"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="14"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="16"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="18"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="20"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="22"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="24"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="26"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="28"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <Label Name="lblSuchen"  Content="_Suchen" Target="{Binding ElementName=edtSuchen}"/>
                <TextBox Name="edtSuchen" Width="150" ToolTip="Bitte Suchbegriff eingeben. Suche Starten mit der Enter-Taste" KeyDown="edtSuchen_KeyPress" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
                <Label Name="lblErsetzen" Content="_Ersetzen"  Target="{Binding ElementName=edtErsetzen}"/>
                <TextBox Name="edtErsetzen" Width="150" ToolTip="Bitte Begriff eingeben, durch den der Suchbegriff ersetzt werden soll. Ersetzen Starten mit der Enter-Taste" KeyDown="edtErsetzen_KeyPress" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="3" />
                <Grid>
                    <CheckBox Name="ChkBarrierefrei" Content="Editor ba_rrierefrei"   Margin="10" Click="ChkBarrierefrei_CheckedChanged" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="4"/>
                </Grid>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <TextBox Name="TBXEditor" DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinWidth="525" MinHeight="240"  AcceptsReturn="True" FontSize="{Binding Path=SelectedValue.Content, ElementName=ComboboxFontsize}" FontFamily="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboboxFontname}" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="5" GotFocus="TBXEditorBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TBXEditorBox_LostFocus">
        </TextBox>
```

If the checkbox "ChkBarrierefrei" has the focus and I press the tabulator key, then the textbox "TBXEditor" does not get the focus, but the comboxbox "ComboboxFontname". This means I can not get out of the toolbar with the Tab key. What can I do against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the ToolBarTray and/or ToolBar `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"`. The TextBox control should get focus now after the last `CheckBox` when you press the tab key.

Here's the MS link regarding the different enum values - [KeyboardNavigationMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You are great! It Works. Thank you so much.

Comment: WPF is very big with a steep learning curve. There's a lot of these sort of properties buried in there. Good luck!